# Spring Boot data-rest Jakson JSONSerializer empty

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, jackson

I've a Spring Boot project 1.3.3-Release that I've deployed on to a Web Logic 12c App Server. This code works fine on the embedded tomcat but not when I deploy on to Web Logic.

I've a Spring Data-Rest Repo

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "car", path = "car")
public interface CarRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Meter, Long>
{
    List<Car> findall();
}
```

My Car POJO

```
@Table(name="car")
@Entity
public class Car
{
   @Id
   @Column(name="ID")
   private Long id;

   @Column(name="manufacturer")
   private String manufacturer;

   .......
}
```

Everything starts up and the web page loads and when I make the rest call I can see the from SQL output the SQL Query executing fine but I then get the below error in my server logs:

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer.isEmpty(Ljava/lang/Object;) at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:528)

I'm assuming the data-rest is trying to automatically map the JSON Response from the endpoint into the Car object but it's failing for some unknown reason.

I've seen from the below link that there was a problem with Spring-Hateoas which I know spring-data-rest uses but seems as I'm using the latest version of spring-data-rest this shouldn't be a problem.

[spring-hateoas error](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/407)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the solution is I had to tell weblogic specifically in the weblogic.xml to load the com.fasterxml.jackson packages from the application and not from it's own container.

```
<wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</wls:package-name>
```

Full weblogic.xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" 
                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                                          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd 
                                          http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app 
                                          http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>12.2.1</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>/ws/car</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor> </wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a version mismatch issue with JsonSerializer class. I think your weblogic classloader is loading an older version of com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind, where the class JsonSerializer doesn't have the isEmpty Method.

From the docs :

```
/**
 * Method called to check whether given serializable value is
 * considered "empty" value (for purposes of suppressing serialization
 * of empty values).
 *<p>
 * Default implementation will consider only null values to be empty.
 * 
 * @since 2.0
 */
public boolean isEmpty(T value) {
    return (value == null);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. It's a maven project so it's defined in there what version to load so I'm confused as to how weblogic would override that?

Comment: What I was saying is, when the app startup inside of Weblogic, weblogic might have a conflicting version of the above mentioned class and is loading it from it's classpath. That is why your app works when ran standalone with the embedded tomcat

Comment: Sorry for getting back to this so late but your answer helped me a long the way to getting the right result. I had to tell the weblogic server to use the com.fasterxml.jackson package from the application and not use it's own one. Thanks very much @anwarc